# How to construct a Rails for a many-to-many model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a User, a Wiki, and a Collaborator model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wikis
  has_many :collaborators
end

class Wiki < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wikis
  has_many :collaborators
end

class Collaborator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :wiki
end
```

When I am editing a Wiki's collaborators I would like the form to look something like this:
[image]

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to construct the form. I thought the following would work but `<% form_for :collaborator do |f|%>` doesn't result in anything being included in the resulting page.

```
<% form_for :collaborator do |f|%>
    <% possible_collaborators.each do |user| %>
        <%= check_box_tag 'wiki[collaborator_ids][]', user.id, wiki.collaborators.include?(user) %>
        <%= user.name %> 
        <br />
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you didn't post your controller code I can't be entierly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I think you are missing out on the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), [tutorial with controller code](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through)).

Furthermore I can only recommend you the use [simple_forms](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) or [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic) as those gems do a good job when it comes to complex forms and help you a lot with the basic use cases.